# Double-capture a token

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4, grammar

I have a SQl language where it allows strings that are double- or single-quoted, i.e., `'hello'` and `"hello"`. Additionally, it may have a `JSON` object, and within a JSON object, only a double-quoted string is valid, so we can have something like this in SQL:

```
SELECT "one", 'two', JSON "hello", JSON {"x": 2}
```

In other words, I'd like to have two string-constructions:

```
String_Literal_SQL: " ... " | ' ... ';
String_Literal_JSON: " ... ";
```

But, these would be 'fighting' to pick up the double-quoted string. Is the answer to this to push the rule from the Lexer to the Parser, and have different tokens for the strings, i.e., doing:

```
string_literal_SQL: Double_Quoted_String | Single_Quoted_String;
string_literal_JSON: Double_Quoted_String;
```

For whatever reason the above feels a bit hack-ish, but then again I don't think there's a way to consume a single token two ways.

Comment: I don't think that's hackish at all. A token is whatever it is; the syntax expresses how the token is used. Maintaining that separation between tokenisation and grammar helps organize your parse.

Comment: Your solution seems fine. The alternative would be to add a `mode` to the lexer grammar where it would go into it when `JSON` found. In this mode, you'd have to count opening and closing braces. Once a closing brace is found, pop the `mode` to go back to the default. Remember: the lexer generally works independently from the parser, and cannot be guided by the parser.

Comment: @kaby76 that was what I though at first with the `mode`, but it seems difficult to determine when to get out of the mode, for example, if the JSON value is something like `JSON [[[[[{{{{{{{{...}}}}}}}]]]]]]` when do we get out?

Comment: You'd have to count the open bracket as well, as it could be an object `{ ... }` or an array `[ ... ]`. If you really want to be fancy, make an entire JSON grammar in lexer rules with `fragment` and return a token for the entire JSON string. You wouldn't need to write any target-specific code, and all counting would be done by the lexer engine. You'd enter that JSON grammar only when you see the `JSON` string, and return only one token after that, popping the mode.

Comment: @kaby76 hmm, that sounds pretty tricky. There is one implementation of `json` rules shown here but how could that be massaged into a `fragment` rule? https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/json/JSON.g4

Comment: @kaby76 ha actually looking at that it looks like you wrote it! :)

Comment: I didn't write it, but I may have modified it for some reason. Anyway, add `mode json_mode;`, and insert the json.g4 after that. Change all rules in the mode to begin with an uppercase letter. Remove the "-> skip" for WS. Then add `fragment` to all rules in the mode except `Json`, which is the "start" rule for this mode: `mode json_mode; Json : Value -> popMode; ...`. Should work.

Comment: @kaby76 very cool -- out of curiosity, why do you remove the `WS` skip here? What if there is a json value such as `[1, 2, 3]` which has spaces within the object?